# WordPress - echo Advanced Custom Field in a .js file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m enqueue’ing scripts based on WordPress page template, and I need those scripts to be able to echo out ACF values. To make things more complicated, my script files dynamically build up HTML which includes custom fields e.g.:

```
innerHTML = '<img src="<?php echo the_field('ad_banner'); ?>"'
```

Is it possible to echo these fields in a .js file, to build up those HTML strings?

I've tried using wp_localize_script like below but am obviously doing something wrong:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pagination-retailers' );
    wp_localize_script('pagination-retailers', 'script_vars', array(
    'banner' => get_field("ad_banner")
    )
);
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Please do basic research before asking. https://www.google.com/search?q=use+php+in+javascript+file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `wp_localize_script()` its create you javascript object the name is the second argument in the function.

so you can call it in your javascript file like this

```
innerHTML = '<img src="'+script_vars.banner+'"';
```

you can also check the object in your page source code. it will be after the js file.

Comment: A-ha. I'd misunderstood how to call the object from wp_localize_script(). Thank you very much